# would it cause memory leak if I don't set a var to nil before assigning it a new allocated memory?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, memory-leaks, nsstring

So I have the following class. The setName could be called many times for a same data instance. Now the question is, if don't do the _name = nil; before assigning it a new string (allocated memory), would it cause memory leaks?

```
// data.h
@interface data : NSObject
{
@private
    NSString *_name;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;

// data.m
@synthesize name = _name;

- (void)setName:(NSString *)name {
    _name = nil; // <-- if don't do this, would it end up causing memory leak?
    _name = [NSString alloc] initWithString:name;
}
```

Comment: note: one would just use `copy` in the real world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your particular case, you won't get a memory leak. This is because of how @synthesize sets up the setter method for you. In the case of a strong property attribute, your setter looks like this:

```
- (void)setName:(NSString *)newName {
    [newName retain];
    [_name release];

    _name = newName;
    return _name;
}
```

It basically takes care of the memory management for you. First it retains the newName, before releasing it (incase name and newName are the same, releasing first would crash your app). Then it releases the old name and assigns newName to your _name ivar

Comment: He has overwritten the automatic setter, how it would look like doesn't matter!

Comment: The point was to show how the strong attribute type is supposed to handle the memory management. If he is going to override the automatic setup, he would at least need to implement the above code to prevent leaks.

Answer (score 1):

The property *name* in your code has a strong modifier so I assume you are using ARC. In that case, no, it won't cause a memory leak.

Comment: and if he wasn't using ARC, writing @property(nonatomic, retain) should also take care of the memory management too.

Comment: @philsquared yes, but in this case he has a custom setter, so the old value for _name_ must be released before assigning the new value.

Answer (score -1):

No, it will not cause a memory leak. But, if you do not initialize the var before using it, you will never know which memory portion is using right now. I.e. you would like to think that it holds a `nil` but perhaps it's pointing to a random place in memory where other vars' data lives. You could mess up with your app's data doing this.

Comment: I thought that, before using it, the var will be automatically initialized to be nil at runtime. Isn't that true?

Comment: @tom It is true. ivars are always initialized with zero when you create an instance.

Comment: Just try not to initialize them and see what happens.